# Possibilities with a force-manipulating device

Tags: physics

What if, sometime in the next say 600 years, humanity develops a device capable of manipulating the four fundamental forces in the area around it. (For example, a handheld device could work in a radius of a meter, while a device the size of a car would be significantly more powerful.) The effects, which would be limited by the speed of light (as if a beam had to travel to the location to be effected) would fall under three categories: Amplification, Nullification, and Inhibition. For example, these categories would be apparent in the example of gravity by: creating a gravity well, removing the effects of gravity in an area, or reducing how effective gravity is in an area. Given this technology, barring social consequences, what applications could be developed  (useful or just plain fun)?. Also, is there any way to make the device follow the conservation of energy, or does just increasing and decreasing the power it takes relative to the effect it's modifying work?

Comment: I'm having some scale issues...by increasing the effects of electromagnetism, is it at the scale where a more efficient mag-lev train could be made?  Or is it at the scale where it's simply going to cause molecular breakdown as electrons orbits around a protons nucleus is suddenly out of whack?

Comment: @Twelfth either, the tech is scalable.

Answer (score 3):

Since reduction is essentially a lower-powered form of negation, the system can be organised into the following (G = gravity, E = Electromagnetism, W = Weak, S = Strong):

With the exception of gravity and weak force, manipulating the other forces to any significant degree would result in disintegration or effective disintegration.

G+ , G- are no different from directly changing the acceleration on the object, which would be perceived no differently from an accelerating spaceship or a rotating space station. Note that changing the *weight* of an object does not change its *mass*, and acceleration would still be limited by your mass.

E+ and E- would significantly disrupt molecular binding, as molecular orbitals would become significantly changed due to the modified energy levels. Thus, they would result in effective disintegration of the targeted object. Even minimal amounts of E+ and E- will result in effective protein denaturation, due to the sensitivity of proteins to small changes in electrostatic forces (eg from addition of acids)

W+ and W- will increase and decrease the rate of quark flavour switching and therefore beta nuclear decay. When applied to normal matter, increasing W would result in non-radioactive elements becoming beta-radioactive, and enhancing the radioactivity of beta-radioactive elements (such as 32P/35S). Decreasing W will allow beta-radioactive isotopes to be made non-radioactive.

S+ and S- are without doubt the most dangerous powers of this machine. Both will result in either massive amounts of nuclear fusion (S+) or fission (S-), and release of massive amounts of radioisotopes.

Comment: Interesting, I like it, but I see you didn't cover nullification of the forces in an area. Would that do anything other special?

Comment: What's up with the plus- and minus- signs?

Answer (score 0):

There's a book that deals with this, Influx by David Suarez. Now, it was a bit complex for me, but they go in to great detail about the different technologies and weaponizations that could be made if you have the ability to affect gravity.

**Spoilers below!**

For instance, in a large enough area, nullifying gravity alone could cause an entire army to just float up and disappear into the sky, rip buildings out of the earth, and give characters the ability to fly at incredible speeds (once you got used to controlling lack of gravity and your current momentum). The possibilities on that one are endless.

Comment: This book does not appear to cover anything but gravity from what I can tell, and however interesting, i'm looking for specific cases on gravity, and the more exotic cases.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer to me is that you now have a source for infinite energy.  take a huge object, nullify gravity so it raises, then reassert and strength gravity on the way down.  Connect this to a wheel that can be rotated to produce electricity and you have an energy source.  With nearly infinite free energy you can do ANYTHING.  space travel would be trivial, especially since you can nullify gravity anyways.  However, you can accelerate objects horizontally at great speeds as well by simply not caring about the cost.

Many people have discussed a post-scarcity world before, but that is why you would have.  It's an entire different way of viewing the world, with all kinds of affects on society and the world economy.

Comment: Nullifying gravity would not also simultaneously nullify inertia. Additionally, if the act of nullifying gravity uses more energy than input into it, it would not be possible to create a perpetual motion device.

Comment: true, but once you nolify gravity you can lift the object up for very little energy expense, just enough to overcome it's inertia and a little for air resistance.  far less then what is received back.  If the device actually has to put in enough energy to nullify a force it would require HUGE energy input, to the point that a hand held device like he mentioned simply isn't feasible.

Comment: I would assume some form of conservation and the energy required to nullify the gravity would be the equivalent needed to lift that distance, no?

Comment: You would need to provide energy equal to the 'weight' of the object per second.  However, there is also the *atmosphere* around the object, which weights quite a bit more.  If you assume that you neutralize only gravity of the object and not atmosphere above it then you would still have to fight the weight of the atmosphere above it pushing you down.  I suppose you could provide enough 'counter gravity' to lift the object and atmosphere, but at this point why not just use a pulley?  trying to rig up anything that exact would be at least as hard as rigging a simple machine and just as costly.